# GoogleMaps API3 ReferenceError: rd is not defined on line 39 of main.js

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am getting the following error in GoogleMaps API3

> ReferenceError: rd is not defined on line 39 of main.js reported by
>   Firebug.

https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_gb/mapfiles/api-3/17/3/main.js

```
function Pr(a,b,c) {
    for(var d = 0, e = 0,f = K(a); e < f && (b(a[e]) && (a[Yc](e--, 1), d++), d !=c ); ++e)
    return d
}

function Qr(a,b) {
    return rd[a] = b
}

Ff[F].Wa=Qr(3, pd("k")); etc etc
```

Running the contents of main.js through the prettifier at http://jsbeautifier.org/ the fragment looks like this at Line 2418:

```
function Qr(a, b) {
   return rd[a] = b
}
Ff[F].Wa = Qr(3, pd("k"));
Q[F].Sd = Qr(0, function () {
    return l[Cc](this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y)
});
```

No references to rd anywhere else in the file. The only references to Qr are the two above.

This is not stopping it working it is just irritating.

Comment: this is a problem with Firebug, does it appear in Chrome? (FYI: https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Test%20Summary%20Reporter&groupby=&sort=&id=7501

Comment: I too experience the same problem, but only with FF when Firebug is open.  Would like to figure out why...